# Moving MS Access from on PC to another

Tags: microsoft-access

I have MS Access on a PC and during the course of a rebuild will need to install it on a different hard drive, I have the CD it came on but no longer have a CD drive. Is there a way to copy to the MS Access files to a flash drive and copy them across to the new drive. I have tried this but just get a bunch of messages about missing installation files and needing the CD.

Comment: Why not copy the CD to an USB drive and install from there? This is 100% supported with MS Office

Comment: You have to install the program, you just cant copy files and expect it to work. Do as Eugen suggests.

Comment: As I mentioned I don't have a CD drive.

Comment: What is the version of MS Access? Was it only MS Access or part of MS Office?

Comment: @patkim It's MS Access 2007 standalone.

Comment: 2007 is too old to be available for download I guess even on third party sites. You may like to look for a computer with CD/DVD drive so that you can create an .ISO file from your original CD and then maintain that ISO. It can then be mounted in virtual CD software on Windows and you can run the installer from therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still find copies of Access 2007 or Office 2007 floating on the internet.
To be downloaded only from well-known websites (!).
This is legal, as long as you use a legal serial key for the product and don't use
it on more than one computer.

The main problem will be to get the serial key in order to activate the product:

- It may be in a sticker on the CD
- It may be possible to extract it from the existing installation using a product
  such as [NirSoft ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html)
  or [Belarc Advisor](https://www.belarc.com/products_belarc_advisor).

Comment: I have the serial number, the CD, the case, the receipt, just no CD drive. All dressed up and now where to go lol.